RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 64, 3, 3], expected input[1, 8, 64, 5000] to have 64 channels, but got 8 channels instead
I am trying to load my data (raw ECG signals stored in .mat files) and convert them to tensors so I don't have to store all the data in a dictionary and then feed it into the vgg16 model. I think this error occurs because there is the problem when data moves from the first layer to the next one. the data shape before the input is Input shape before model: torch.Size([8, 12, 5000]) which is supposed to  be correct.

class ECGDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, directory, labels_df):
        self.directory = directory
        self.labels_df = labels_df

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels_df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        filename = self.labels_df.iloc[idx]['Filename'] + '.mat'
        filepath = os.path.join(self.directory, filename)
        data = loadmat(filepath)['val']
        data = data / np.max(np.abs(data))  # Normalize data

        numeric_label = self.labels_df.iloc[idx][['Class_0', 'Class_1', 'Class_2', 'Class_3', 'Class_4', 'Class_5']].values
        label_indices = [i for i, val in enumerate(numeric_label) if val == 1]

        # Convert to binary indicator matrix
        y_binary = np.zeros(num_classes, dtype=int)
        for label in label_indices:
            y_binary[label] = 1

        return torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.float32), torch.tensor(y_binary, dtype=torch.float32)

labels_file_path = '/content/Labels.csv'
labels_df = pd.read_csv(labels_file_path)

directory = '/content/Data/Final_data'
dataset = ECGDataset(directory, labels_df)

train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])

batch_size = 8
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

class CustomVGG1D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(CustomVGG1D, self).__init__()
        self.vgg16 = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
        self.vgg16.features[0] = nn.Conv1d(12, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1) 
        self.vgg16.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(4096, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Forward pass through the modified model
        x = self.vgg16.features(x)  # Convolutional layers
        print(f'After Conv layers: {x.shape}')  # Check shape after conv layers

        # Flatten before passing to classifier
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten
        print(f'After flattening: {x.shape}')  # Check shape after flattening

        x = self.vgg16.classifier(x)  # Fully connected layers
        return x

num_classes = len(labels_df.columns) - 1 
model = CustomVGG1D(num_classes=num_classes).to(device)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00001)
scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'min', patience=5, factor=0.5)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 20
train_losses = []
val_losses = []
best_loss = float('inf')
epochs_no_improve = 0
patience = 5
clip_value = 1.0  # Gradient clipping value

print(f'Input shape before model: {inputs.shape}')

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)  # Move to device
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        if torch.isnan(loss).any():
            print(f"NaN detected in loss at epoch {epoch + 1}")
            break
        loss.backward()
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip_value)  # Gradient clipping
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()

    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    train_losses.append(train_loss)

    # Validation phase
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in test_loader:
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)  # Move to device
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            val_loss += loss.item()

    val_loss /= len(test_loader)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    scheduler.step(val_loss)

    print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}')

    # Early stopping logic
    if val_loss < best_loss:
        best_loss = val_loss
        epochs_no_improve = 0
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model.pt')
    else:
        epochs_no_improve += 1

    if epochs_no_improve >= patience:
        print("Early stopping triggered")
        break

I tried:
    def forward(self, x):
        # Forward pass through the modified model
        x = self.vgg16.features(x)  # Convolutional layers
        print(f'After Conv layers: {x.shape}')  # Check shape after conv layers

        # Flatten before passing to classifier
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)  # Flatten
        print(f'After flattening: {x.shape}')  # Check shape after flattening

        x = self.vgg16.classifier(x)  # Fully connected layers
        return x

